# simple_form how to pass parameters in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I want to batch update records by simple_form,

[image: screenshot of simple form]

The code is as below:

```
    = simple_form_for url: batch_update_admin_tuitions_path, method: 'put' do |f|
      table.table
        thead
          tr
            th.text-center
            th.text-center column1
            th.text-center column2
            th.text-center column3
        tbody.text-center
          - @tuitions.each do |tuition|
            tr
              td = f.input_field "user_ids[]", as: :boolean, value: tuition.user_id
              td = @users_hash[tuition.user_id].name
              td = tuition.num
              td = tuition.sum_amount
      = f.submit :Submit, class: 'btn btn-success'
```

But it doesn't work.

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"FDpxyq9LE8UjxBjIm4lstj29N86Xlja+czWZXDdMcnehgBzmh0zz7aE5ZKqGWCWtX/h+iRwnTE048IPPodG10w==", "/admin/tuitions/batch_update"=>{"user_ids"=>[]}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

I found a problem: the user_ids is blank. How to pass the user_ids to params?

Answer (score 0):

From the SimpleForm documentation, there are a few helpers provided:

[collection_check_boxes:](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collection-check-boxes)

```
form_for @tuition do |f|
  f.collection_check_boxes :user_ids, User.all, :id, :name
end
```

[if you have an association](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations), you can use `as: :check_boxes`:

```
<%= simple_form_for @tuition do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :users, as: :check_boxes %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

More generally, I think SimpleForm uses `f.input` instead of `f.input_field`, so your code should read:

```
td = f.input "user_ids[]", as: :boolean, value: tuition.user_id
```